# How do I apply a formula to a range without applying said formula to every cell?

Tags: regex, string, google-sheets, match, array-formulas

I'm trying to apply a formula without having it add the formula data to each and every cell - in other words, I need the cells that are receiving the formula to be untouched until they get their data.

I was searching around and it looked like an ARRAYFORMULA would work but it doesn't seem to be doing anything when I apply it.

For example, I want to apply this formula to a cell range: `=SPLIT(E2, ","))`. Each cell in the E column needs to be split into two the two adjacent cells next to it based on it's comma. When I try to apply `=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(E2:E99, ","))` only the cell I add this to gets the formula.

Comment: That must indeed be possible. Can you share some example data (preferably) in a shared (public) spreadsheet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want may be `array_constrain` but for your example I can only at present offer you two formulae (one for each side of the comma):

```
=Array_constrain(arrayformula(left(E2:E,find(",",E2:E)-1)),match("xxx",E:E)-1,1)  

=Array_constrain(arrayformula(mid(E2:E,find(",",E2:E)+1,len(E2:E))),match("xxx",E:E)-1,1)
```

Comment: Could I ask for one more little trinket of knowledge from you if possible, I need to apply the same rational but for a column full of hyperlinks that I want to place in the adjacent column without their =hyperlink() attached, so it would just show the raw link. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the contribution of pnuts, also try:

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(","&E2:E,"^"&REPT(",+[^,]+",COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,1,6))-1)&",+([^,]+)")))
```

Note: the last parameter of OFFSET can be changed to match the maximum number of values you have in the cells of the range E2:E (separated by a comma).  E.g: if you have a no more than 3 values per cell, set it to three. The output will then be three columns wide (one column for each value). 
Hope that makes sense ? 
Also credits due to AdamL who (I believe) orginally crafted this workaround.